# Equivalent of R igraph graph_from_data_frame() function in Python igraph?

Tags: python, r, igraph

Is there an equivalent of this igraph [R function](http://igraph.org/r/doc/graph_from_data_frame.html) in Python igraph?

> graph_from_data_frame(d, directed = TRUE, vertices = NULL)
>
> This function creates an igraph graph from one or two data frames
>   containing the (symbolic) edge list and edge/vertex attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python does not have data frames so there is no direct equivalent. The closest equivalent could be [`Graph.DictList`](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#DictList), which creates a graph from a list of dictionaries, or [`Graph.TupleList`](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#TupleList), which is the same for a list of tuples.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you can use this:

```
from igraph import Graph
g = Graph.DataFrame(edges, directed=False, vertices=vertices, use_vids=False)
```

where "edges" is a Pandas dataframe with the edges, vertices are the names that will be used in each vertex, and use_vids if you want to assign indexes to name the edges instead of using the "vertices" data

https://igraph.org/python/api/0.9.7/igraph.Graph.html#DataFrame

Comment: Thanks! Woah, I realized this question dates back from almost 8 years ago. Time flies...